# Is it possible to restrict an instance of a pagetype in EpiServer?

Tags: c#, content-management-system, episerver

Under Start I want the user to only have the possibility to create one instance of my EmailTemplatePage pagetype. Is it possible?

Comment: Was the answer by Ted Nyberg what you were looking for? Or are you trying to limit the amount of EmailTemplatePage instances to one - as in no more than one (1) page of that type can be created by the editor under Start?

Comment: the later. I just wonder if it is possible to limit the mount of EmailTemplatePage instances to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be that you create the single page, and then set "Available in edit mode" to false on the page type. Then it will not be possible for editors to create another page (but they can still make a copy of the existing page).

If your requirement is that an editor should be able to create just one page of a specific page type in a specific part of the page tree, you would need to create a custom validation when the page is saved.

Something like this: https://blog.wsol.com/improving-episervers-content-editing-experience-through-validation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `AvailableContentTypes` attribute on your start page type:

```
[ContentType]
[AvailableContentTypes(Availability.Specific, Include = new [] { typeof(EmailTemplatePage) })]
public class StartPage : PageData
{
}
```